# chrome.exe --headless not working at all anyways

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to run `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="B:\chrome" --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot="B:\chrome\_screenshots" https://example.com/` from PowerShell (elevated), the command exits itself immediately without any error or error file. It doesn't create the screenshot either. Why? What can I do now? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying a window size

```
&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --screenshot="$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\chrome.png" --window-size=1980,960 "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

This will create a 1980x960 png on your desktop called "chrome.png"

Also, you probably have tons of chrome.exe processes running in the background, close them with task manager or something.

Also!

If you're looking into properly automating these screenshots,
have a look at [Puppeteer](https://www.testim.io/blog/puppeteer-screenshot/) or Selenium, and [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) in general.

Answer (score 0):

So the trick was that you should specify a file, not a directory (which doesn't create anything).

Incorrect:

```
--screenshot="B:\chrome\_screenshots"
```

Correct:

```
--screenshot="B:\chrome\_screenshots\chrome.png"
```